# Pasar variables entre activitys al dar click en un item de un listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, arraylist, arrayadapter

Buenos días, tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo un ListView donde muestro datos de una base, al darle click a un item paso los datos a otro activity, pero como guardo todo en un string me pasa todo los datos (En el primer activity necesito mostrar todos esos datos por eso esta el string con todo) y solo necesito pasar el ID para luego ese id meterlo en un request y meterlo en un select para traer el detalle de ese id de otra tabla.
Mi problema es que no se o no encuentro la forma, o directamente la lógica de como esta programado es pésima, pero no puedo pasar solo el id, me pasa el string con todos los datos y con eso no puedo mandar el request.
¿Me guían por favor?

Esto es a lo que necesito llegar:

```
RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
parametros.put("IdPedido", ID);
```

Asi lleno el listView:

```
public ArrayList<String> obtDatosJSON(String response){
ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    String texto;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){

        texto = "\n" +
                "Barrio: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("barrio") +"\n"+
                "Dirección: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") +"  "+
                "Piso Depto: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("pisoDepto") +" "+
                "Cliente: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente") +"\n"+
                "Telefono: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefono") + "\n" +
                "Estado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado") + "\n" +
                "Cadete Asignado: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cadete") + "\n";
        listado.add(texto);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return listado;
}
```

Y asi paso los datos al otro activity:

```
public void CargarLista(final ArrayList<String> datos){
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
listado.setAdapter(adapter);
listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Detalle.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID", datos.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan acabo de ver la pregunta en la otra, te contesto allí para no abrir dos discusiones distintas del mismo caso.

Comment: @Carmen ¿cuál pregunta? Puedes marcar esta pregunta como duplicada haciendo referencia a su otra pregunta

Comment: Justo esa, gracias x4mp73r